# Ubuntu re-install. Will the existing partition be overwritten?

Tags: system-installation

If I try to install again, will it add yet another partition to my HD or will it overwrite the one already there?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what you pick during installation.

You get choices depending on your current setup. Pick "overwrite" current or something else and pick what the system needs to format or add to your new setup.

It will only give the choice to add to the current installation (aka. create a multiple boot) if there is free space on a partition.

Answer (score 2):

The system will ask you what to do.  Overwrite an existing partition or not.